# Link from react router dom change the align of my Card from Boostrap

Tags: css, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have some Cards made with Boostrap, they look like this.

[image]

```
function TimeLine(props) {
  return props.data.map(
    ({ screenName, name, imageProfile, description, timeAgo }) => (
      <TwitterCard
        screenName={screenName}
        name={name}
        imageProfile={imageProfile}
        description={description}
        timeAgo={timeAgo}
      />
    )
  );
}
```

Nevertheless if I add the component Link from react router dom, I got this.

[image]

```
function TimeLine(props) {
  return props.data.map(
    ({ screenName, name, imageProfile, description, timeAgo }) => (
    <Link to={`/username${screenName}`}>
      <TwitterCard
        screenName={screenName}
        name={name}
        imageProfile={imageProfile}
        description={description}
        timeAgo={timeAgo}
      />
      </Link>
    )
  );
}
```

How could I keep the align and avoid these underlined text? Is there some alternative to Link? Or a correct approach to do this? Notice that I'm interested in make the Card clickeable so I can use link there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply CSS/style to make them ***not*** block-level elements.

Example:

```
function TimeLine(props) {
  return props.data.map(
    ({ screenName, name, imageProfile, description, timeAgo }) => (
      <Link
        key={`/username${screenName}`}
        to={`/username${screenName}`}
        style={{ display: "inline" }}
      >
        <TwitterCard
          screenName={screenName}
          name={name}
          imageProfile={imageProfile}
          description={description}
          timeAgo={timeAgo}
        />
      </Link>
    )
  );
}
```

Since the `TwitterCard` component is the component enforcing the flex/grid layout though the link should be moved *into* the `TwitterCard` component inside the `Col` component.

Example:

```
const TwitterCard = ({
  screenName,
  name,
  imageProfile,
  description,
  timeAgo
}) => {
  return (
    <>
      <style type="text/css">
        {` 
      .bg-customBlack {
        background-color: #26262C;
        color: white;
      },  
    `}
      </style>

      <Col md={4} className="p-2">
        <Link to={`/username${screenName}`}> // <-- link here inside column component
          <Card bg="customBlack" className="text-center">
            <Card.Header>
              @{screenName} - {name}
            </Card.Header>
            <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title>
                <Image width={65} height={65} roundedCircle src={imageProfile} />
              </Card.Title>
              <Card.Text>{description}</Card.Text>
            </Card.Body>
            <Card.Footer className="text-muted">{timeAgo}</Card.Footer>
          </Card>
        </Link>
      </Col>
    </>
  );
};

function TimeLine(props) {
  return props.data.map(
    ({ screenName, name, imageProfile, description, timeAgo }) => (
      <TwitterCard
        key={screenName}
        screenName={screenName}
        name={name}
        imageProfile={imageProfile}
        description={description}
        timeAgo={timeAgo}
      />
    )
  );
}
```

[image: Edit link-from-react-router-dom-change-the-align-of-my-card-from-boostrap]

Comment: Hi, thanks! I just tried but didn't work, same result

Comment: @Omar Think you could create a small, *running* codesandbox demo of this code that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: Hi again! Tried this [DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/embed/loving-spence-0q1lrw?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) which is almost the same code I'm using. I'm pretty new at frontend, I'm not sure why the card Isn't showing up correctly even if the imports are added. I hope it helps tho.

Comment: @Omar No worries, there's likely a missing import of the minified bootstrap CSS. I've forked your sandbox, added the CSS import, and fixed the layout. The `Link` should be rendered *inside* the column right next to each card component. I've updated my answer. Please check it out when you've a chance.

Comment: thanks again! now it's aligned but the underlined text is there, how could I get rid out it? Sorry for all these stupid questions and thanks once again! :)

Comment: @Omar Apply a `text-decoration: none` CSS rule to the link. For example, in the sandbox I did `style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}`, but you could add a CSS classname and do it there just as well.